# How do I remove certain elements from a string[] which contains multiple elements C#

Tags: c#

```
string[] allFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
```

That gives me the full path (e.g. C\users\franz\pictures) but if I want just "pictures" so that I can put it in the code below

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"dlclist.xml");
            lines[0] = (allfolders[1]);
            File.WriteAllLines(@"dlclist.xml", lines);
```

Comment: `string[] allFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(directory).Select(d => Path.GetDirectoryName(d)).ToArray()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're wanting to make this more dynamic or add to a loop, but based on your question then something like:

```
var name = new DirectoryInfo(allFolders[1]).Name;
```

EDIT: adding loop code

```
foreach (var folder in allFolders)
        {
            var name = new DirectoryInfo(folder).Name; 
            // do stuff
        }
```

NOTE: this only gets the name of the dirs under the current path.  So if you're path is C:\tmp you'll only get the next level down.

Comment: Yes I'm planning to add to a loop